# Cant make voice calls from web page inside android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I have an application with a webView, which loads a list of contact details which users are allowed to make Voice calls by clicking that number. In the web page **tel:** tag is used.following is the code I have written.

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        if (uri.toString().startsWith("tel:"))
            makePhoneCall(uri.toString());
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
```

---

**makePhoneCall()**

```
public void makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
    checkPermissions();
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phoneNumber)));
}
```

}

***the issue is..***

After installing on many devices, on some devices users, can't make the call, on clicking the number nothing happens. I am sure the touch event is happening because 5 seconds after clicking the number a pop up appears which works fine.

Some of the devices are Nokia, Asus Zenfone Max with android Oreo.

I have checked android versions most devices have 6+ android version.

- I am running the webView on a different thread created from onCreate();

while on other devices everything works fine.

I can't seem to figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of ACTION_CALL, you will need no call permission in your app while using ACTION_DIAL, it will just open your dialer with number already entered in it and will allow user to decide if they really want to call or not.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String Url) {
    if (Url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(Url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try providing run time permission for everything sometimes when only specific devices with latest android versions create issues it's kind of more related to runtime permissions and version compatibility.

Comment: I am checking that in the makePhoneCall method.I have added that above.

Comment: and it was working fine in all devices this starts showing up all of a sudden

Comment: @JeffinJ it would be more helpful to debug if you can share the log of device where app is causing issues

Answer (score 1):

Both answers above are correct. **Mr.patel's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55293286/11152084) said it was caused because of run time permission error. But even after handing it there were issues in some devices.

So, I tried **MDB's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55293762/11152084), and it is working fine.

Comment: Cheers dude! Good luck